# Is there a way to send message/notification through an app I'm developing with a Toast or AlertDialog from a server/computer

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm a total newbie in Android programming and I was wondering if it's possible to push a message or notification to my app from a server or computer and displays the message through a toast or an Alert Dialogue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can start with **Google Cloud Messaging for Android**

For more info see http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

and may start with these tutorial

Using  **PHP and MySQL**

[Android Push Notifications using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), PHP and MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

and using **asp.net**

[Google Cloud Messaging for Android.](http://www.tejaprakash.com/2013/02/google-cloud-messaging-for-android.html)

[Push Messages to GCM server using visual c#.net application (server side).](http://www.tejaprakash.com/2013/05/push-messages-to-gcm-server-using-net.html)

Comment: Does the GCM able to send an in-App Messages through a Toast or AlertDialog?  The device I'm working on is sorely depend on the d-pad and there's no notification menu (the one usually found in phoned when you do slide down starting from the top of the screen) available.  It's running on Jelly Bean though

Comment: @user3195396 is there any similar menu for notification,I always did GCM with notification and then able to open dialog from notification.

Comment: Nope, no menu notification.  That is why I need the message to display out in my app through either a Toast or AlerDialog

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a free service like [www.AskingPoint.com](http://www.AskingPoint.com) (full disclosure in the Founder) to send Push or In-App Messages to your Apps. The Advantage of something like AskingPoint is that you can more easily target users using rules and also quickly and easily localize the message into other languages. Hope that helps. Our Android SDK Beta will be out next week.

Comment: That's what exactly I'm looking for - In-App Messages.  But do you have any tutorial or something?  The website you provided is just throwing things like signing up for free..

Comment: Look at the Support link at top of page. No signup needed to see all docs: http://www.askingpoint.com/support Tutorials are in there, but only ones visible are for iOS. Android will be up late next week.